# Can't pass associative array to vue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, laravel-5.6, laravel-blade

I have array like this.

```
$array = ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2];
```

I want to pass it to Vue But it can not.

```
<my-component :array="'{!! json_encode($array) !!}'"
></my-component>
```

But the output is show like this in html.

> ":1,"b":2}'"="">

Comment: Vue.js can't handle associative arrays, so I don't see the purpose of this. You should bring it in a form that Vue.js understands.

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
$array = ["a" => 1, "b" => 2];

<my-component :assoc-array='{!! json_encode($array) !!}'></my-component>
```

Comment: But it got string not object.

Comment: i got this while run `{"a":1,"b":2}`

Comment: OK my bad i was run `new Vue` in side of HTML element that already run `new Vue`, That why is doesn't work.